# How to detect a L-shaped gesture in android?

Tags: android, listview, swipe, gesture

I'm currently building a file manager that will use gestures for its action, that's why I need to have this kind of gesture. I've already tried searching for some similar topics here but I just can't find something that will give me some idea on doing it. All I found are about SimpleGestureListener (which I already used) and that GestureOverlayView (which I think is not good for my app). I thought I could apply the idea from the onFling Method, but I realized that it is not applicable for the L-shaped gesture that I'm aiming... To make it simple, here's the thing that I want to know:

[image]

So, what  I need to figure out is how can I detect the point between the horizontal and vertical swipe. Is there any other method that i can use to detect that point on my ListView? I just need some ideas on how to do it and I know I can figure it out. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to implement a `onTouch()` event for your listview to detect the user touch pattern. Here is a pseudo-code of how I would approach this:

```
@Override
public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {

    switch (motionEvent.getActionMasked()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            //Get the X and Y values the user touched down first
            mDownX = motionEvent.getRawX();
            mDownY = motionEvent.getRawY();

            break;

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE: {
            float deltaX = motionEvent.getRawX() - mDownX;
            float deltaY = motionEvent.getRawY() - mDownY;

            if (deltaX > myMoveToTheRightThreashold
                && Math.abs(deltaY) < myNoYmoveThreashold) {
                moveToRight = true;
            }
            if (moveToRight && deltaY > myMoveUpThreshold) {
                myLShapedGesture = true;
                return true;
            }
            break;
      }
      return false;
}
```

I did not test this at all and I'm just trying to give you the idea of how to approach. You probably need to add a `case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP` to detect when the user stopped touching the device and execute your desired action there.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for giving me some ideas on how to do it. Let me just experiment with these codes and I will get back here if I made it. Thanks.